# C++ parallel execution and thread_local object destruction

Tags: c++, multithreading

I need some clarification regarding thread_local object destruction. The first question is when does it happen? C++ reference says the following:

> The storage for the object is allocated when the thread begins and
> deallocated when the thread ends. Each thread has its own instance of
> the object. Only objects declared thread_local have this storage
> duration.

Unfortunately, it's not always obvious when a thread ends. Let's consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <mutex>

struct MyClass
{
    MyClass()
    {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        std::cout << "ctor" << std::endl << std::flush;
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
        std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl << std::flush;
    }

    static std::mutex mtx;
};

std::mutex MyClass::mtx;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> v(1000000, 3);

    std::transform(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), [](int x)
    {
        thread_local MyClass myclass;
        return x * x;
    });

    std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Intuitively I would expect that threads end when `std::transform()` call returns. However, it looks like thread_local objects of MyClass continue to live until the end of the program. Moreover, some of them don't get destroyed at all. This leads me to another question.

When I tested this sample code in MSVC 2019 (16.8.6), there were several constructors called, but always only one destructor:

```
ctor
ctor
ctor
ctor
ctor
done
dtor
```

I have read [another post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/thread-local/798234) about this behavior in MSVC. If I understand correctly, the issue is caused by Windows system thread pool and must be Windows-specific. So I decided to test it on Linux with GCC 9.3.0:

```
ctor
ctor
ctor
ctor
ctor
ctor
done
dtor
dtor
dtor
dtor
```

Now multiple destructors are called, but still in the example above we can see an unmatched number of constructor and destructor calls. Is it a bug or a designed behavior? How can it be justified?

Comment: gcc 10.2 on Linux, compiled with `-std=c++17`, produces exactly one constructor and destructor call. Try adding a copy constructor, logging it, and see what happens.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Try running it several times. It may work differently.

Comment: Same results, every time.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What if you increase the vector size?

Comment: @mentalmushroom Little out of topic hint: Don't do std::endl << std::flush. std::endl already does a flush.

Comment: @AndreasBrunnet For some reason without std::flush the end of line was not always printed

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Reproduces on my GCC/Linux. I got as many constructions as I have logical cores, and varying number of destructions.

Comment: Well, I got 32 cores, and all I could get is one construction and destruction...

Comment: Mine is version 9.3.0

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Seems like for whatever reason the algorithm fell back to sequential execution instead of parallel which also explains why there is only one ctor and dtor printed. Its the same thread -> thread_local -> only one construction at the beginning. "If the implementation cannot parallelize or vectorize (e.g. due to lack of resources), all standard execution policies can fall back to sequential execution."

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Long-shot: Are you linking with `tbb`? [This is my output with `-fsanitize=address`](https://pastebin.com/ZSgVvrr3)

Comment: What happens if you limit the scope of the TLS, i.e. `{ thread_local MyClass myclass; }  return x*x;`

Comment: Also, what happens with thread-local-storage when thread-pooling is used?  Would the same thread be used multiple times to perform a number of separate transforms, and would that affect lifetimes of objects created and destroyed?  Is it possible that multiple instances of the same object are being created at the same location in memory - instead of destroying instances, perhaps the constructor is being used to reinitialise storage that is already allocated?   Just thinking aloud here....

Comment: @Den-Jason If a thread is reused for the function, then the thread local *shouldn't* be recreated. It should use the one instance that was created once.

Comment: From the above, I wonder if some of those log-entries are never being *printed,* thereby producing misleading results.  The output is buffered to print but the print never occurs.

Comment: MSVC delegates `std::async` to the program's default [thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/thread-pool-api). The default thread pool is created at program startup and destroyed *after* program termination. There is no cleanup possible for the default thread pool, that's by design. So don't put anything that needs explicit cleanup in the TLS (note - it is not necessary to release memory at program termination, all memory is released anyway).